# Date dependent login with shiro

Tags: java, shiro

Is it possible creating date dependent logins with apache shiro? This would mean that I would be able to specify that a specific user can authenticate into an application only between certain dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend the realm you are using and override the method `doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)` if the date condition is not met:

```
public class DateRealm extends JdbcRealm {

  @Override
  protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token)
      throws AuthenticationException {
    Date date = new Date();
    if ( /* Your dat condition here */ true) {
      return super.doGetAuthenticationInfo(token);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I rely on the IniRealm, is there a possibility?

Comment: Well, just interchange `extends JdbcReam` with `extends IniRealm`